Can't find a way to embed a lot of large files into a vectorstore
I have a group of large files that I want to store in a vector store. But splitting the text and embedding is taking several hours.
I tried a lot of different settings for the text splitter and different vector stores but it doesn't change much. There's no data that I can delete to make the files smaller and dividing the files in smaller ones still takes a lot of time, what can I do to solve this?
